# How to drop duplicates from PySpark Dataframe and change the remaining column value to null

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Pyspark. 
I have a Pyspark dataframe and I want to drop duplicates based on the id and timestamp column. I then want to replace the reading value for the duplicate id to null. I do not want to use Pandas. Please see below:

Dataframe:

```
id       reading      timestamp
1        13015        2018-03-22 08:00:00.000        
1        14550        2018-03-22 09:00:00.000
1        14570        2018-03-22 09:00:00.000
2        15700        2018-03-22 08:00:00.000
2        16700        2018-03-22 09:00:00.000
2        18000        2018-03-22 10:00:00.000
```

Desired output:

```
id       reading      timestamp
1        13015        2018-03-22 08:00:00.000        
1        Null         2018-03-22 09:00:00.000
2        15700        2018-03-22 08:00:00.000
2        16700        2018-03-22 09:00:00.000
2        18000        2018-03-22 10:00:00.000
```

How do I need to add to this code:

`df.dropDuplicates(['id','timestamp'])`

Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using Window function to count duplicates over partition `id, timestamp` and then update `reading` depending on the count:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("id", "timestamp").orderBy("timestamp")

df.select(col("id"),
          when(count("*").over(w) > lit(1), lit(None)).otherwise(col("reading")).alias("reading"),
          col("timestamp")
          ) \
  .dropDuplicates(["id", "reading", "timestamp"]).show(truncate=False)
```

Or using group by:

```
df.groupBy("id", "timestamp").agg(first("reading").alias("reading"), count("*").alias("cn")) \
  .withColumn("reading", when(col("cn") > lit(1), lit(None)).otherwise(col("reading"))) \
  .select(*df.columns) \
  .show(truncate=False)
```

Gives:

```
+---+-------+-----------------------+
|id |reading|timestamp              |
+---+-------+-----------------------+
|1  |null   |2018-03-22 09:00:00.000|
|1  |13015  |2018-03-22 08:00:00.000|
|2  |18000  |2018-03-22 10:00:00.000|
|2  |15700  |2018-03-22 08:00:00.000|
|2  |16700  |2018-03-22 09:00:00.000|
+---+-------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

On Scala can be done with groupping, and replacing "reading" values with null where count is more than one:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 13015, "2018-03-22 08:00:00.000"),
  (1, 14550, "2018-03-22 09:00:00.000"),
  (1, 14570, "2018-03-22 09:00:00.000"),
  (2, 15700, "2018-03-22 08:00:00.000"),
  (2, 16700, "2018-03-22 09:00:00.000"),
  (2, 18000, "2018-03-22 10:00:00.000")
).toDF("id", "reading", "timestamp")

// action
df
  .groupBy("id", "timestamp")
  .agg(
    min("reading").alias("reading"),
    count("reading").alias("readingCount")
  )
  .withColumn("reading", when($"readingCount" > 1, null).otherwise($"reading"))
  .drop("readingCount")
```

Output is:

```
+---+-----------------------+-------+
|id |timestamp              |reading|
+---+-----------------------+-------+
|2  |2018-03-22 09:00:00.000|16700  |
|1  |2018-03-22 08:00:00.000|13015  |
|1  |2018-03-22 09:00:00.000|null   |
|2  |2018-03-22 10:00:00.000|18000  |
|2  |2018-03-22 08:00:00.000|15700  |
+---+-----------------------+-------+
```

Guess, can be transalted to Python easily.